# Почему глагол "поди" выражает предположение или удивление в значении вводного слова?

Tags: этимология, семантика

Из словаря:

**ПОДИ**. Разг. I. повел. 1. Пойди (пойдите). П. сюда. Подите прочь. 2. Попробуй (попробуйте), попытайся (попытайтесь). Поди сосчитай! II. в зн. вводн. сл. Наверное, должно быть, надо полагать. **Устал старик, поди, за день.** **Далеко, поди, с этих гор видно!**  III. в зн. частицы. Выражает удивление, изумление. **И вот, поди же, встретились через десять лет!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Поди* — разговорное от *пойди.* Это всем понятно — на всякий случай уточнил.

Выскажу предположение.

***Поди*** или ***поди-ка*** в качестве ***предположения:*** по(й)ди посмотри, проверь — тогда, **скорее всего,** и окажется так, как я говорю.

***Поди же*** как ***изумление:*** вот **"пошёл** бы ты мыслью" в будущее в прошлый раз (когда виделись), ни за что бы не подумал, что доведётся встретиться.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем. Я тоже так думала, но хотелось узнать мнение других.  "И вот, поди же..." Здесь примерно то же значение, то есть:  поди посмотри, как получилось, встретились же.

Comment: Рад, что вам понравился ответ! Ну да, можно и так интерпретировать. Это уже нюансы, я похожее имел в виду. :)